# Largest Eigenvalue of Matrix Associated to a Vertex Shift (Symbolic Dynamics, Topological Entropy)

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, entropy

Let $\Sigma_{m}:=\{(\ldots,x_{-1},x_{0},x_{1},\ldots):x_{i}\in\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}\}$. We define $X\subset\Sigma_{2}$ to be the subshift of finite type that has $000$ and $111$ as its only forbidden words. I want to calculate the topological entropy of the left shift map $\sigma\colon X\to X$.

It can be shown that if $Y$ is a vertex shift (i.e. induced by a graph), then the topological entropy of the left shift map on $Y$ is equal to the logarithm of the largest eigenvalue of the adjency matrix $A$ associated to the graph $\Gamma$ (i.e. $a_{ij}=1$ iff there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ in $\Gamma$). Also, two conjugate dynamical systems have the same topological entropy. For a more detailed explanation, check [Brin-Stuck, Chapter 3 (and 2)](https://www.fisica.net/ebooks/caos/Brin%20ans%20Stuck%20-%20%20Introduction%20to%20Dynamical%20Systems.pdf).

So I tried to construct a conjugacy $c\colon X\to Y\subset\Sigma_{4}$ (i.e. a surjective continuous map $c$ such that $\sigma\circ c=c\circ\sigma$), where $Y$ is a vertext shift. Inspired by the proof of proposition 3.2.1 in Brin-Stuck, I defined $c(x)_{i}:=x_{i}x_{i+1}$ (where $x_{i}x_{i+1}$ is a word of length $2$). Note that $\{00,01,10,11\}$ are the allowed words that occur in $X$ of length $2$. So $Y$ is a vertex shift with the following graph  $\Gamma$ (sorry for bad graphical representation):

- $00\to01$
- $01\to10$, $01\to11$
- $10\to00$, $10\to01$
- $11\to10$

Then the associated matrix is given by $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1\\ 1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is given by $$\lambda^{4}-\lambda^{2}-2\lambda-1.$$ But I think it is way to hard to calculate the zeroes of this polynomial algebraicly (which should be doable, since it is an exercise from an old exam). Am I missing something? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\lambda^4-\lambda^2-2\lambda-1=\lambda^4-(\lambda+1)^2$.

Comment: @JohnB Thank you! This is quite embarrassing haha, I feel stupid that I overlooked this fact.

Comment: We all have been caught in this! :)